# Will EE work with php 5.5.10 okay?

Tags: php, server, compatibility

Quick question regarding whether anyone knows of any issues with installing EE on a server running the latest version of php (5.5.10 as I write this)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm running EE 2.8.1 on PHP 5.5.10 and I've not noticed any problems so far. You should be safe.

Comment: Same thing for me, using PHP 5.5.10 months ago, and no problems related.